# How to fix invalid literal for int() with base 2: ' ' in python?

Tags: python

this is my code:

```
num = [x for x in input().split(',')]
for p in num:
    x = int(p, 2)
    if not x%5:
    items.append(p)
print(','.join(items))
```

And the error is File < input>, line 4, in < module>. Then it states that there's a value error which is what is in the title.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the input you're providing?

Comment: `print(",".join([int(x, 2) for x in input().split(',') if x and not int(x, 2) % 5]))`

Answer (score 0):

Your code as written requires that the input be in the form of binary numbers (0 or 1) separated by commas, e.g. `10100,1010,10,1,100`.  The error you got indicates that you entered two commas with nothing between them (`,,`).

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure to strip all whitespaces off and check if each `p` got at least a value:

```
_input = '1,,,,, 101,      1, 1011, 10110001       '
#num = [x.strip() for x in input().split(',')]  # remove all whitespaces arround the number
items = []
num = [x.strip() for x in _input.split(',')]
for p in num:
    if not p:  # if p is empty/None, skip it!
        continue
    x = int(p, 2)
    if not x%5:
        items.append(p)
print(','.join(items))
```

Output:

```
101
```